# Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused (gedit:2652): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:19:10.568: cannot open display:

Tags: networking, server, java, gedit

Whenever I try editing a file such as test.java with gedit it always gives me this error.

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:2652): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:19:10.568: cannot open display:
```

I have looked at other cases when gedit does not open the display but I am not skilled enough to understand what exactly people are doing since it isn't exactly the same error.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You have tagged your question `networking`: can we assume you are trying to execute `gedit` on a remote host? If so, please [edit] your question with details of how you are doing that.

Comment: I think xhost + or something like that should work; I had the same issue before, and now that I enabled access for everyone, at the least I have fewer errors. :-) (Evince has a symbol error on my computer right now in addition to that.)